# Facing Problem While Running WordPress Hook For Archive, Categories, Author, Date Pages Only

Tags: php, javascript, hooks

I wrote below code but facing issue to run it only on archive, categories, author, date pages to improve page speed.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>

<script>

if( is_archive || is_category() || is_author() || is_date()) {

  // targets spans containing text
  let CalendarPrevBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-calendar-nav-prev");
  let CalendarNextBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-calendar-nav-next");

  // stores spans text
  let PrevBtnText = CalendarPrevBtn[0].textContent;
  let NextBtnText = CalendarNextBtn[0].textContent;

  // deciding if btn needs to be hidden
  Array.from(CalendarPrevBtn).forEach((x) => {
    if (!PrevBtnText.trim()) {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      // x.style.display = "block";
    }
  });

  Array.from(CalendarNextBtn).forEach((x) => {
    if (!NextBtnText.trim()) {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      // x.style.display = "block";
    }
  });

}
</script>

<?php } );
```

When I run this code it says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: is_single is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those functions are JavaScript functions. They're PHP functions. You need to run them outside the `<script>` tag in the PHP:

```
add_action(
    'wp_footer',
    function () {
        if ( is_archive() || is_category() || is_author() || is_date() ) {
            ?>
            <script>
                // etc.
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
);
```

You were also missing the `()` on `is_archive`.

Comment: You're the man! Such a helpful answer. You made my day :)

Comment: if you did want to run them only in JS though, correctly built themes put a lot of classes on the `<body>` tag which include classes that tell you if you're on a page/archive/post/category/etc. Inspect the `<body>` tag on the page you want and you should see them, and can look for them in javascript